# PhoneGap Hybrid app using WCF services

Tags: cordova

I want to develop a Hybrid app that connects to WCF services that in turn access Sharepoint services. I am new to both PhoneGap and Hybrid app development. How should I go about it?

Comment: This is far too broad a question for this forum.

Comment: Your question is too abstract. What have you tried so far ? Where have you got stucked ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of reading ahead of you I'm afraid!

I would use jquery ajax to connect to basichttp wcf services. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472488(v=vs.110).aspx

For WCF to sharepoint microsoft has a good set of guides on msdn:
I can't post anymore links, but if you google it it will work

Good luck